# SharePoint 2010 Workflow, Document Creation - Alert Users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and have a requirement to make a database entry to our database for document creation. I need to find a way to get all SharePoint Groups associated with the document when it is created. Is there a way to do this through a workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can create custom Sandbox action 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798499.aspx

Comment: I'll look into it, do you know of a way to query SharePoint to get the groups who have access to a document/folder?

Comment: you will have to do some googling for that. you can try reffering below links http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-files-folders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx ; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f2feef2e-731e-4ee3-ac66-4d75243ef83f/programmatically-copy-folders-permissions-from-one-document-library-to-another-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious